# ¿Cómo obtener una suma del mismo input?

Tags: javascript, html

Teniendo un input:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Suma"/>
```

y luego introduzco en el input:

```
2 + 4
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que se sumen?, solo mediante expresiones regulares?, ¿no hay más métodos?

Comment: ¿Solo serán validas las sumas de numeros positivos?

Comment: No se indica lo buscado/investigado ni lo intentado.

Answer (score 5):

Para validar ese tipo de expresiones es posible usar [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/eval):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', iniciar, false);

function iniciar() {
    var input = document.getElementById("evaluar");
    input.addEventListener("click", evaluarExpresion, false);
}

function evaluarExpresion() {
    var prueba = document.getElementById("prueba");
    console.log("Evaluando: " + prueba.value);
    console.log(eval(prueba.value));
}
```

```html
<input id="prueba" type="string" placeholder="Expresión">
<button id="evaluar">Evaluar</button>
```

Sin embargo, ten en cuenta la advertencia con respecto al uso de `eval()`:

> **No utilice eval innecesariamente**
>
> eval() es una función peligrosa, quel ejecuta el código el cual es
>   pasado con los privilegios de quien llama.  Si ejecuta eval() con una
>   cadena de carcteres que podría ser afectada por un elemento malicioso,
>   podría terminar ejecutando código malicioso dentro de la computadora
>   del usuario con los permisos de su página o extensión web . Más
>   importante aún, una parte del código de terceros podría accesar al
>   ámbito en el cual eval() fue invocada, lo que puede permitir la
>   entrada a posibles ataques de formas a las que el constructor Function
>   (art. en inglés) el cual es similar, no es susceptible.
>
> eval() es generalmente también más lenta que otras alternativas desde
>   que se invoca en el intérprte de JS, mientras que otros muchos
>   constructores son optimizados por los motores JS modernos.
>
> Existen alternativas más seguras (y rápidas) que eval() para casos de
>   uso común.

Por ejemplo, intenta evaluar `alert("Hola");`. Estás permitiendo que el usuario ejecuta código JavaScript, lo cual es peligroso. Incluso podrías hasta reemplazar la función del evento `click` del botón. Tomáte el tiempo para saber lo que pasa cuando evaluas esto en el input:

```
document.getElementById("evaluar").addEventListener("click", function() { console.log("Hola!"); })
```

(una pista, recién va a funcionar cuando le des click al botón por segunda vez, pregúntate por qué).

---

Existen otras opciones que tal vez sean más seguras como, por ejemplo:

- [exrp-eval](https://github.com/silentmatt/expr-eval)

Answer (score 1):

En Javascript, se puede usar `eval()`, que ejecuta un string como si fuera parte del programa.

Así que puedes hacer:

```
  var campo = document.getElementById("campo");
  var texto = "resultado = " + campo.value + ";";
  var resultado = 0;
  eval (texto);
  campo.value = resultado;
```

```js
function calcular() {
  var campo = document.getElementById("campo");
  var texto = "resultado = " + campo.value + ";";
  var resultado = 0;
  eval(texto);
  var mostrar = document.getElementById("resultado");
  mostrar.innerHTML = resultado;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Javascript example no.2</h1>
<input type="text" id="campo" value="2+4" />
<input type="submit" id="boton" value="Change" onclick="calcular()" />
<div id="resultado">Aquí vendrá el resultado</div>
```

Naturalmente, si no validas el valor que te pasa el usuario, puede pasarte instrucciones con "efectos colaterales"

Answer (score 1):

Hola la función eval de javascript puede sumar un string, he realizado un ejemplo con un evento blur es decir escribes la operación en tu input y al salir (perder el foco en el input "da un click afuera del input para perder el foco") (puedes usar el evento que más te convenga) la suma aparece automáticamente:

```js
var form = document.getElementById("form");
form.addEventListener("blur", function( event ) {
  var rep = eval(document.getElementById("operacion").value);
  document.getElementById("operacion").value = rep;
  event.target.style.background = "pink";    
}, true);
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" id="operacion" placeholder="Suma"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Con eval es una opción pero nada recomendable, es mejor hacer tu propio algoritmo.

Si son solamente sumas puedes hace un split del signo **+** y sumar los elementos del arreglo:

```js
var sumas = document.getElementById("suma").value;
var valores = sumas.split("+");
var resultado = 0;

for(var i=0; i<valores.length;i++){
  resultado+= parseInt(valores[i],10);
}

console.log(resultado);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="suma"  placeholder="Suma" value="1 + 2 + 3"/>
```